# Bootstrap nav-tabs not working with Angular $routeprovider

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, route-provider

I am using AngularJs and Bootstrap. While I am using `$RouteProvider` for SPA, I am using bootstrap for the layout. This is working fine.

However, I am now trying to use Bootstrap nav-tabs to have tab based navigations.

My HTML is like this:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/mis"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> TrigonMeter</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul id="tabs" class="nav navbar-nav nav-tabs container-fluid" data-tabs="tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a data-target="#db" href="#db" data-toggle="tab">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a data-target="#admin" href="#admin" data-toggle="tab">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a data-target="#mis" href="#mis" data-toggle="tab">MIS</a></li>
                    <li><a data-target="#fin" href="#fin" data-toggle="tab">Finance</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-link">Hi {{globals.currentUser.username}}</li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" ng-click="logout()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
```

For the tabs. This works fine. And the following is the `tab-content` section:

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!--[if lt IE 7]>
                <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->
            <div class="row">
                <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content col-sm-2 col-md-2 sidebar">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="db">
                        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#/admin/org">Organisation Details</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/mis/jobno/">Job Numbers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/mis/jobexpenses/">Job Expenses</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/mis/jobfindet/">Job Financial Details</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/mis/contracts">Contracts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="admin">
                        <h1>Admin</h1>
                        <p><a href="#/admin/org" data-toggle="tab">Organisation Details</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="mis">
                        <h1>MIS</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#/mis/jobno/" data-toggle="tab">Job Numbers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/mis/jobexpenses/" data-toggle="tab">Job Expenses</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/mis/jobfindet/" data-toggle="tab">Job Financial Details</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/mis/contracts" data-toggle="tab">Contracts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="fin">
                        <h1>Finance</h1>
                        <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                    <div ng-view></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But The tab-content section is not working.

Please do let me know if I could explain the problem.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not clear what you are expecting from that link or what higher level issue really is. Perhaps you want html5Mode ?

Comment: Sorry @charlietfl, I updated the question. Somehow I was too cryptic as was feeling bit lazy in the weekend.

Comment: OK..that's better. Switch to using `angular-ui-bootstrap` and get rid of `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. I quickly read through angular-ui-bootstrap once. However, it seems to be a bit tough to recreate the bootstrap nav-tab using it. Can you point me to any sample/example?